# Files not opening as read-only in VB.NET when read-only attribute set

Tags: vb.net, attributes

I'm having trouble with a bit of code designed to intentionally open files as read-only. My team often needs to be able to peek into each others' files without locking the file owner out, so in a form being designed for document management I want users to be able to open files optionally as read-only.

Coming from VBA I'm still somewhat new to VB.NET and also bitwise operations generally, but I believe the "read-only" interpretation of [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes?view=netframework-4.8) from MS Docs has been correctly implemented:

```
        Dim attributes As FileAttributes
        attributes = File.GetAttributes(path)
        If Not (attributes And FileAttributes.ReadOnly) = FileAttributes.ReadOnly Then
            ' Make file readonly.
            File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) Or FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        End If

        ' Open the file
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)

        ' Reset the file to read/write.
        attributes = RemoveAttribute(attributes, FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        File.SetAttributes(path, attributes)
```

When I use "GetAttributes" before and after the line to open the file I get a return of 1 or sometimes as 33, which the [FileAttributes enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=netframework-4.8) documentation suggests is correct for what I'm trying to do. Before and after the attribute change "GetAttributes" returns 128 or in certain cases 32, which also should be correct.

However despite the fact the above code appears correctly implemented and seems to be producing the correct affect in the file's attributes, files opened this way (namely Excel files) open as read-write. I'm also fine with other ways of opening a file read-only provided that it can be used equally well on any document you would commonly encounter in an office setting (Excel, Word, etc.) with its default program. That being said, I've tried several methods and haven't had any success, and this one by far has seemed the cleanest and most promising.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Process.Start()` runs the associated executable, then you remove the attribute from the file when the application you've run is just beginning to start. The file has not been accessed yet. When the application opens the file, the read-ony attribute is long gone. Maybe you want to subscribe to the Process' `Exited` event, so you're notified when the Process ends and you may remove the attribute at this time.

Comment: The `/r filePath` command line switch can also be used to open a file in read-only mode.

Comment: @Jimi - Brilliant! Makes perfect sense, because a few of the times when I was stepping slowly through code it worked just fine. This is the reason I love stack overflow - looked at that for way too long and it never popped out.

Comment: @Jimi - Good idea on the /r filepath. Thought it might have only been for Excel - ran into that somewhere but I'll give it a shot if I don't have to worry about switching attributes back and forth. Thanks! I'll post an answer with whatever I end up going with.

Comment: @Jimi - Do you have any example code for either proposed solution? Your first response prompted me to dive into learning events - which I'm excited to learn about - but for my current skill level it may be a rabbit hole for this issue. I had previously looked into the second one but am having a hard time finding the proper way to implement. Will "/r filePath" work with non-Excel files, and what does the implementation of this actually look like?

Comment: The `/r` switch works for Excel only. Access has `/ro`. WinWord opens in read-only mode with `/h` only SharePoint non-checked out documents, but it can open a document in Protected View mode with the `ViewProtected` Verb. It can be set with `ProcessStartInfo.Verb = "ViewProtected"`. I don't know whether PowerPoint supports any read-only switch. If you need a code sample, I can modify your code to let the Process start a file with the read-only attribute set (as you have done) and waits asynchronously for it to terminate, using the `Exited` event, to reset the attribute back to what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi I was able to come up with the solution. In my application Excel files are the most important to open in ReadOnly so I'm happy with an Excel-only solution for the time being. While his answer for using and releasing attributes was great it had the problem of not restoring the attributes to their default until the file is closed, which to my understanding would cause others to also open the file ReadOnly while the file is open. The point of this in my application is to "peek" at a file without locking other users on a network out of ReadWrite access, so unfortunately his-well-thought out solution won't work.

I was however able to use the /r switch with a bit of investigating. It was a bit tricky (for someone of my skill level) since some switches need to be placed before the file path and some after. Solution below:

```
Process.Start("EXCEL.exe", "/r " & Chr(34) & path & Chr(34))
```

Answer (score 2):

> As described in comments, the file attributes are restored to their
>   previous state right after the `Process.Start()` command: the
>   application that opens the file has not been started yet; when it
>   finally access the file, the read-ony attribute has already been
>   removed.
>   A possible solution is to subscribe to the `Process.Exited` event and restore the original file attributes when the Process termination is notified.

A modified version of your code: the [EnableRaisingEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents) property causes a process to raise the [Process.Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event. I subscribed to the event using an in-line delegate (a Lambda), but I added an example that uses a standard delegate method using the `AddressOf` operator (since you said you have to learn about events).

Since we want to *run* a file and not an executable, we need to also set [`UseShellExecute = True`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute), so the Shell will find and execute the registered application associated with the file extension.
If `UseShellExecute = True` is not specified, an exception is raised (the file is not an executable).

The name of the file to execute is assigned to the [Process.StartInfo.FileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename)

When the Process terminates, the **`Exited`** event is raised. In the event handler, the file attributes are restored to the previous state.

```
Private Sub SomeMethod(filePath As String)
    ' filePath is File's Full path
    Dim attributes As FileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath)
    File.SetAttributes(filePath, (attributes) Or FileAttributes.ReadOnly)

    Dim proc As Process = New Process()
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = filePath
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True

    AddHandler proc.Exited,
        Sub()
            File.SetAttributes(filePath, attributes)
            proc?.Dispose()
        End Sub
    proc.Start()
End Sub
```

If you want to use a standard method as the `Exited` event handler, you have to declare the **`filePath`** and **`attributes`** variables in a different scope. Neither can be a local variable, they won't be accessible from the method delegate.
If you need to run just one file, these can be instance fields (declared in the scope of the current class).

If you instead can have multiple processes running different files, all waiting for the associated applicationt to terminate, these informations should to be stored in a list of objects, a Dictionary or a similar container.

For example, using a Dictionary, declared as a Field:
<sub>(the Dictionary Key is the File path. If a file can be opened multiple times - a `.txt` file maybe, use a different identifier)</sub>

```
Private myRunningFiles As New Dictionary(Of String, FileAttributes)
' (...)

Private Sub SomeMethod(filePath As String)
    Dim attributes As FileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath)

    If Not myRunningFiles.ContainsKey(filePath) Then
        myRunningFiles.Add(filePath, attributes)
    Else
        ' Notify that the file is already opened
        Return
    End If

    Dim proc As Process = New Process()
    ' (... same ...)
    AddHandler proc.Exited, AddressOf OnProcessExited
End Sub

Protected Sub OnProcessExited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim proc = DirectCast(sender, Process)
    Dim filePath = proc.StartInfo.FileName
    Dim attributes = myRunningFiles(filePath)
    File.SetAttributes(filePath, attributes)
    myRunningFiles.Remove(filePath)
    proc?.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much for this! I've already learned a ton from your posts. I'm just now realizing however that modifying attributes and releasing on Exited wouldn't release the file for others to access in read/write mode (files are being shared over a network) until the application (Excel, for example) terminates, correct?